# If and Then basic

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and I want to test a basic If and Then Statement.  I want to create a message to say Yes or No based on the data in cell A1 in excel named score. I had tried many things and sometimes just all the messages pop up so wondering how to write this properly?

Here is the actual statement:

```
Sub IfTest()    
Dim Score As Integer    
Dim Msgbox As String

Score = Cells(1, 1).Value

If Score = 1 Then    
    Msgbox = "Yes"
Else    
    Msgbox = "no"
End If    

End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim Msgbox As String` isn't a good idea since `Msgbox` is a built-in function.

Comment: Also, if you are learning VBA, I recommend that you forget that `Integer` even exists as a possible type. It is a 16-bit integer and such things are no longer able to index all possible rows since they overflow at 32,768. With a 32 or even 64 bit word size, such 16 bit numbers are probably stored in a memory slot which is actually bigger than 16 bits, so there is no memory savings. Use `Long` instead. Similarly, use `Double` rather than `Single` for your floating point type.

Comment: Thank you two John Coleman, Scott Craner, and Flazer.  I removed Dim and = to fix them and now they both works great :)...I guess dont need to define variables if built in functions and I made already some syntax for msg box.  but now it works after those corrections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to VBA!

```
MsgBox "This is my message", , "This is my Title"
```

Between the commas, you insert button styles.
Button styles and Title are optional.

So for your example, remove the "="'s and instead do:

```
If Score = 1 Then
    Msgbox "Yes"
Else
    Msgbox "no"
End If
```

Check out the MS link: [MsgBox Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445082(v=vs.60).aspx)

*** **EDIT per [comintern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4088852/comintern)'s comment - remove this line** !!!!!!

```
Dim Msgbox As String
```

Comment: Note that you also have to remove `Dim Msgbox As String` or it's a compile error.